# How to randomly generate numbers each time the program is run and store those values in a list?

Tags: python, list, random

I am writing a program that asks the user to input a list of students. Once the list is made the user can input a student's name that was listed before to show 4 random integers from 1 to 100 that represent 4 different marks on assignments. When I run this program, however, the mark is the same number each time. How do I run the program so that each number for the mark is different, also how can I store these values in a separate list? Thank You!

```
def printMark(studentMark, studentName):
    print("Enter the names of your students")
    print("Press the enter key to store another name. print q or Q when you're done.")
    names = input("Enter student name: \n")
    classlist = []

    while True:
        names = input("")
        if str.lower(names) == 'q':
            break
        classlist.append(names)

    for name in classlist:
        print(name)

    student_choice = input("Enter a students in your classlist: ")
    if student_choice not in classlist:
        print("That students is not in your class")
    elif student_choice in classlist:
        mark = list(range(1, 101))
        print("A1:" + str(studentMark) + "\nA2:" + str(studentMark) + "\nA3:" + str(studentMark) + "\nA4:" + str(studentMark))

classlist = []
import random
mark = list(range(1, 101))
printMark(random.sample(mark, k=4), classlist)
```

Comment: Maybe use `mark = [random.randint(1, 101) for _ in range(4)]`?

Comment: You have a single `studentMark` list that you generate once, pass to `printMark`, and then reuse multiple times inside `printMark`.  Instead, `printMark` should not take a `studentMark` argument (actually it shouldn't take `studentName` either since it doesn't use it), and should itself just call `random.sample(range(1, 101), k=4)` each time it needs to generate random marks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the error is in `print("A1:" + str(studentMark) + "\nA2:" + str(studentMark) + "\nA3:" + str(studentMark) + "\nA4:" + str(studentMark))`.

If studentMark is a list, which is what I gather from my last moment research on `random.sample`, it seems like the problem is that you are using the same value each time rather than different list elements from `studentMark`. (Note that I'm assuming the `random.sample` technique would work like `mark = [random.randint(1, 101) for _ in range(4)]`, but without repeated values.)

Instead maybe use:

```
print("A1:" + str(studentMark[0]) + "\nA2:" + str(studentMark[1]) + "\nA3:" + str(studentMark[2]) + "\nA4:" + str(studentMark[3]))
```

You could also use:

```
print(*[f"A{i+1}: {mark}" for i, mark in enumerate(studentMark)])
```

This would simplify things but is more complicated than the original idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your `printMark` function shouldn't take a `studentMark` argument if the intent is for it to generate a different set of marks each time.  It also shouldn't take a `studentName` argument since it doesn't use it.  You could very easily write this script without any functions at all, and it'd be more straightfoward:

```
import random

print("Enter the names of your students")
print("Press the enter key to store another name. print q or Q when you're done.")
classlist = []
while True:
    names = input()
    if str.lower(names) == 'q':
        break
    classlist.append(names)
print(*classlist, sep='\n')

student_choice = input("Enter a students in your classlist: ")
if student_choice not in classlist:
    print("That student is not in your class")
else:
    for a in range(1, 5):
        print(f"A{a}:", random.sample(range(1, 101), k=4))
```

If you were going to use functions in this script, I'd suggest having one function to enter the class list and another to print a chosen set of marks given a class list:

```
import random

def get_class_list() -> list[str]:
    print("Enter the names of your students")
    print(
        "Press the enter key to store another name.  "
        "Enter q or Q when you're done."
    )
    classlist = []
    while True:
        name = input()
        if str.lower(name) == 'q':
            return classlist
        classlist.append(name)

def print_mark(classlist: list[str]) -> None:
    student_choice = input("Enter a student in your classlist: ")
    if student_choice not in classlist:
        print("That student is not in your class")
        return
    for i in range(1, 5):
        print(f"A{i}:", random.sample(range(1, 101), k=4))

print_mark(get_class_list())
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi firstly 2 questions 1: why you put this program inside a def it just makes it more complicated 2: if the students mark are random why you are taking them as a argument to the def? any ways here is the solution i came up with

```
def printMark(studentName):
    print("Enter the names of your students")
    print("Press the enter key to store another name. print q or Q when you're done.")
    names = input("Enter student name: \n")
    classlist = []

    while True:
        names = input("")
        if str.lower(names) == 'q':
            break
        classlist.append(names)

    for name in classlist:
        print(name)

    student_choice = input("Enter a students in your classlist: ")
    if student_choice not in classlist:
        print("That students is not in your class")
    elif student_choice in classlist:
        mark = list(range(1, 101))
        print("A1:" + str(random.sample(mark, k=4)) + "\nA2:" + str(random.sample(mark, k=4)) + "\nA3:" + str(random.sample(mark, k=4)) + "\nA4:" + str(random.sample(mark, k=4)))

classlist = []
import random
mark = list(range(1, 101))
printMark(classlist)
```

Here: instead of taking student marks a argument i generated them when they are printed this way it generates every time it prints one previously it was taking one random mark and using it 4 times now its all different.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably store the students in a dictionary when you want to bind their name to a list of their marks.
Here is the solution I came up with:

```
import random

students = {}

while True:
    names = input("")
    if names.lower() == 'q':
        break

    # this is list comprehension, you can write 4 times random.randint(1, 100) as well
    students[names] = [random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(4)]


student_choice = input("Enter a student from your list: ")
if student_choice not in students.keys():
    print("This student is not in your list.")
else:
    print(f"{student_choice}:\n"
          f"A1: {students[student_choice][0]}\n"
          f"A2: {students[student_choice][1]}\n"
          f"A3: {students[student_choice][2]}\n"
          f"A4: {students[student_choice][3]}")
```

It generates a list of 4 integers with random values every time a new user is added to the dictionary.
This means that you can access the student's marks later in the code -  unlike your solution, where you only decided what the student's mark was while printing it.

Answer (score 0):

Jhon, looks like your code was really close.  I've made one edit:

```
def printMark(studentMark, studentName):
    print("Enter the names of your students")
    print("Press the enter key to store another name. print q or Q when you're done.")
    names = input("Enter student name: \n")
    classlist = []

    while True:
        names = input("")
        if str.lower(names) == 'q':
            break
        classlist.append(names)

    for name in classlist:
        print(name)

    student_choice = input("Enter a students in your classlist: ")
    if student_choice not in classlist:
        print("That students is not in your class")
    elif student_choice in classlist:
        mark = list(range(1, 101))
        print("A1:" + str(studentMark[0]) + "\nA2:" + str(studentMark[1]) + "\nA3:" + str(studentMark[2]) + "\nA4:" + str(studentMark[3]))

classlist = []
import random
mark = list(range(1, 101))
printMark(random.sample(mark, k=4), classlist)
```

Here's a sample run:

```
Enter the names of your students
Press the enter key to store another name. print q or Q when you're done.
Enter student name: 
a
b
c
q
b
c
Enter a students in your classlist: b
A1:7
A2:93
A3:63
A4:86
```